# In android app how to disable FTM for doing WiFi RTT ranging?

Tags: android, wifi

I have developed a sample app using WiFI RTT. On Pixel 4 its working as expected but its giving ranging failed STATUS 1 on Pixel 6a.

Whereas the Google app WifiRttScan works as it has the option to disable RTT with FTM. So wanted to understand how do I disable FTM for WiFiRTT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am developing a android app using WiFiRtt. Its working fine on Pixel 4 but giving STATUS Code 1 on Pixel 6a. So, tested the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.location.rtt.wifirttscan&hl=en&gl=US . This works fine on Pixel 6a after disabling RTT with FTM. Wanted to try disabling FTM. Did not understand how to do.